# "join me later" vs "later join me"

Tags: word-choice, word-order, grammaticality-in-context

What is "most" correct - and is there a grammatical difference - between these to sentences?

- "You can *join us* **later**."
- "You can **later** *join us*."

To me, the first seems more correct... but I'm not a native English-speaker...

Also, is one "more" active and the other passive?  Is there a term for this?

BTW, would **may** fit better than **can** in the above examples?  I know "can" is more for being *physically able to*, while "may" is more for being *allowed to* - and maybe *wanting to*...

Comment: For can/may see [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19230/2818)

Comment: I cant understand "is one "more" active and the other passive?"

Comment: @Cardinal I was just wondering if it could be something similar to active/passive, eg "Our troops defeated the enemy" (a) vs "The enemy was defeated by our troops" (p)

Comment: Passive sentences with modals follow this rule: **Modals** + **be** + **Past Participle**. So It is obvious that It is not a passive sentence.

Comment: I think you want to make clear that the verb **join** can be both **transitive** and **intransitive**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual place for an adverb of this type is at the end of the clause. Your second example is grammatical, but is very rarely used ([Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=join%20us%20later%2Clater%20join%20us&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cjoin%20us%20later%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjoin%20us%20later%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJoin%20us%20later%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clater%20join%20us%3B%2Cc0)), and sounds awkward. Have you found a sentence like your second example in a textbook or test, or in real life? I can't think why *any* source would include such a sentence.

Comment: I found a similar sentence in a fanfiction-story...  It just sounded "awkward" to me, but at the same time it seemed grammatically-correct - or at least valid.